# How to call both parent class __init__ from base class?

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance, init

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        print("in A")


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, id1, id2):
        print("In B")

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, id1, id2):
        super(C, self).__init__(id1)
        super(C,self).__init__(id1,id2)
```

I am calling C's object as C(1,2).

It throws error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

May I know how to call both parent class' `__init__` from C's `__init__`?

Comment: I went ahead and marked this as a duplicate because if the top answer there doesn't help you, the linked article certainly ought to. Note that the person answering is a major contributor on the Python dev team, so this is pretty authoritative :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, id1, id2):
        A.__init__(self, id1)
        B.__init__(self, id1, id2)
```

Comment: this do not work.

Comment: Sorry, fast answering mistake.